# Custom Shortcut Keys in Visual Studio doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just created a shortcut key for creating new folder in visual studio 2013. When I hit a key, in this example Ctrl + Shift + atl + F nothing happens.

If I look at options for Keyboard and search for Project.AddNewSolutionFolder I can see that my command is there, and it is also a global setting.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, it was wrong setting for keyboard, it should be Project.NewFolder and not Project.AddNewSolutionFolder